# How do I get two gamepads to work with Monaco (or other Steam games)?

Tags: steam, controllers, linux

I'm running Linux and my two controllers are..

- THRUSTMASTER 2-in-1 Dual Trigger Controller
- THRUSTMASTER 3-in-1 Dual Trigger Controller

The problem is that even though I can configure one of them in Big Picture Mode, but neither is there a way to select a controller nor is there a way to configure both of them at the same time. Although I got it working once or twice, but now it doesn't anymore. The is also the case for Guacamelee (and probably many more).

I don't know if it helps, but [**here**](http://www.reddit.com/r/linux_gaming/comments/1k1xe9/using_any_gamepad_to_simulate_xbox360_controller/cdbhrtx) is a way to get the configuration that was made my Big Picture Mode.

So, how can I get two (non Xbox) gamepades work consistently on Linux (with Steam) for local co-op?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it's pretty easy to make the [Steam Big Picture](http://store.steampowered.com/bigpicture/) method work using two gamepads. Here is how:

1. Open a file `NAME.sh` and replace `NAME` with the name of your game
2. Paste the following code and replace `COMMAND` with the command to start the game:

   `export SDL_GAMECONTROLLERCONFIG="LINE
   LINE"
   COMMAND`
3. Plug in the gamepad you want to configure and unplug others
4. Start *Steam Big-Picture Mode*, go to settings and configure your gamepad
5. Open `~/.local/share/Steam/config/config.vdf`
6. Search for `"SDL_GamepadBind" "CONFIG"`
7. Copy the part marked as `CONFIG`
8. Paste it in the abovementioned command as a replacement for `LINE`
9. **Optional:** For every gamepad continue at **3.**
10. Run the file and have fun playing together! :)